# Merging related questions

Tags: discussion

Did anybody notice the following questions are (kind of) the same or can be described as one broad question?

1. [Find all integral solutions to $a+b+c=abc$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176875/find-all-integral-solutions-to-abc-abc)
2. [Solve the equation $a+b+c=abc$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929564/solve-the-equation-abc-abc-for-a-b-c-in-mathbbz)
3. [All solutions of $a+b+c=abc$ in natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613105/all-solutions-of-abc-abc-in-natural-numbers)
4. [Rational solutions to $a+b+c=abc=6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384653/rational-solutions-to-abc-abc-6)
5. [Integer solutions to $ab=a+b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411393/integer-solutions-to-ab-ab)
6. [An equation of the form $A + B + C = ABC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884642/an-equation-of-the-form-a-b-c-abc), [An arctan problem including a Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886070/an-arctan-problem-including-a-diophantine-equation)
7. [From $\tan(1/A) = \tan(1/B) + \tan(1/C)$ to $A + B + C = ABC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884695/from-tan1-a-tan1-b-tan1-c-to-a-b-c-abc)
8. [Sum of digits and product of digits is equal (3 digit number)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202679/sum-of-digits-and-product-of-digits-is-equal-3-digit-number)
9. [Solve $x + y + z = xyz$ such that $x , y , z \neq0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240229/solve-x-y-z-xyz-such-that-x-y-z-neq0)

What does the meta-community think about it? Does it make sense to keep only one alive and (maybe the oldest or that one with maximum views) make the rest archived?

Comment: To me, 1. (=4.) is the best duplicate target. 5. and 6. are not duplicate to 1.

Comment: If you believe that a question is a duplicate of another, please flag that question as a duplicate.  The community can then vote on whether or not to close the flagged question.  This does not require meta discussion.  If you believe that one question is an *exact* copy of another, it is possible to merge questions, but this requires diamond moderator intervention.  You can request such intervention with a custom flag (but please use this sparingly).

Comment: @ArcticChar Oops, [1] and [4] were duplicate. Removed [4].

Comment: I guess that the tags ([meta-tag:exact-duplicates]) and ([meta-tag:merging]) might be suitable here. (I did not edit the tags since I wasn't sure whether your are using the word *merging* as a technical term or in som eother meaning.)

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977926/dfrac1a-dfrac1b-dfrac1c-a-b-c-in-mathbbn-with-no-common-factor-fi